# Video game puzzle

Tags: riddle, rebus, knowledge, video-games

Each line of the puzzle is a different clue which refers to a different game. Once you've solved each clue take the first letter of the game and find the hidden message.

> Man called jon hates jewelry
>   Famous three circles go mad with paint brush
>   Green man gets scared
>   A black and white dance move
>   A man with lots of arms makes coffee
>
> Famous modification
>   Haircut warrior
>   A shepherd leads his heavy flock
>   Joe wormtongue
>   A cat and a robot go on adventure

Comment: Just curious...how did Keelhaul get the mark when ManyPinkHats answered first?

Comment: ManyPinkHats was missing two clues whereas Keelhaul was missing one. It was quite hard to pick who gets the mark

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The message is

> Hello Gamer

The video games are (with some help from @Kant1, @ManyPinkHats & @hagfy):

Man called jon hates jewelry

> Halo (@hagfy)

Famous three circles go mad with paint brush

> Epic Mickey (@ManyPinkHats)

Green man gets scared

> Luigi's Mansion (@Kant1)

A black and white dance move

> Limbo

A man with lots of arms makes coffee

> Octodad

Famous modification

> Garry's Mod (@Kant1)

Haircut warrior

> Afro Samurai (@Kant1)

A shepherd leads his heavy flock

> Mass Effect

Joe wormtongue

> Earthworm Jim (@ManyPinkHats)

A cat and a robot go on adventure

> Ratchet and clank (@Kant1)

Giving

> **Hello gamer**

Answer (score 12):

Some guesses (based on very little)

Man called jon hates jewelry (should be the last one open)

> Halo
> Master Chief is John-117 and he blows up Halos (big rings)

A shepherd leads his heavy flock

> Mass Effect

Joe wormtongue

> Earthworm Jim

Observation:

> @Kant1's ideas spell --L-- GA--R, second word could be GAMER, so my guesses fit into that

Answer (score 8):

Building off what Kant1 and hagfy have already answered

Man called jon hates jewelry

> .

Famous three circles go mad with paint brush

> Epic Mickey

Green man gets scared

> Luigi's Mansion (@Kant1)

A black and white dance move

> .

A man with lots of arms makes coffee

> Octodad

Famous modification

> Garry's Mod (@Kant1)

Haircut warrior

> Afro Samurai (@Kant1)

A shepherd leads his heavy flock

> Mass Effect (@hagfy)

Joe wormtongue

> Earthworm Jim

A cat and a robot go on adventure

> Ratchet and Clank (@Kant1)

Message in the first letters:

> It's not complete, but I think it will end up being, "HELLO GAMER"

Answer (score 7):

Some ideas

Green man gets scared

> luigi's mansion

Famous modification

> Garry's Mod

Haircut warrior

> afro samurai

A cat and robot go on adventure

> Ratchet and clank

Comment: The cat and robot one could also be one of the Robot Wants series, although it's more tenuous.